# how to get json rest response - node.js

Tags: node.js, rest

How can i get JSON objects in the following case:

Here is my post request:

```
var articles = client.post("http://host:port/path", args, function (data, response) {
//  console.log(xml.parseBuffer(data))
   console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
//  return xml.parseBuffer(data);
});
```

result of data.toString('utf8') look like:

```
<WebServiceResponse>
   <page>
     ...
   </page>
   <articleDataList>
      <articleId>
         <idArticle>100000</idArticle>
         <index>test</index>
      </articleId>
      <goodType>test</goodType>
      <idAttributeSubject>100001</idAttributeSubject>
      <identyfiable>false</identyfiable>
      <isActive>true</isActive>
      <isGoodSet>false</isGoodSet>
      <longName>test</longName>
      <translationSubjectId>
         <idTranslationSubject>100408</idTranslationSubject>
      </translationSubjectId>
      <unitCode>szt</unitCode>
      <vatRate>0.2300</vatRate>
   </articleDataList>
   <articleDataList>
     ...
   </articleDataList>
   <articleDataList>
```

...

and xml.parseBuffer(data) looks:
{ name: 'articleDataList', childs: [Object] },

I need put into articles objects with only: idArticle, index and shortName
Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this output:

```
{ name: 'articleDataList', childs: [Object] }
```

`Object` represents javascript object that you need to stringify like this: `JSON.stringify(Object)`

Or you should convert this whole Buffer to string first, and then convert to JSON or javascript object:

`xml.parseString(data.toString('utf8'))`